# Свернуть/развернуть блок при клике

Tags: javascript

Есть задача - увеличивать блок по нажатию "читать подробнее". Так же есть кнопка "свернуть", которая соответственно уменьшает этот блок.

[image: Пример, что должно увеличиваться]

Так вот, я думал сделать через **toggleClass**, но потом не смог придумать как же его закрывать с помощью уже другого элемента "свернуть". И таких блоков будет 8.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/ в jquery уже есть то что вам нужно :-)

Comment: А как нескольким кнопкам дать эту функцию? То есть "читать подробнее" и раскрывает и скрывает элемент, а "скрыть" только скрывает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="1">Toggle</button>
<p>
  This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs.  You
  should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in
  your life.  Congratulations!
  <button id="2">Close</button>
</p>
 
<script>
$( "#1" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).slideToggle( "fast" );
});
$( "#2" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).slideToggle( "fast" );
});
</script>
```

Как вариант

Comment: Да, то что нужно. Спасибо. Я уже сделал это более сложным путём. Через  toggleClass и removeClass и с заданием высоты через классы.

Comment: Возможно не самый верный путь, но главное что проблему удалось решить самостоятельно и это очень хорошо :-)

Comment: Но в будущем буду использовать именно Вашей решение)) Я там ещё один вопрос задал, вдруг и там мне поможете;) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/889373/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8